# How can I open a predetermined vim setup from within a program

Tags: python, vim, split

I've written a python program which processes a list of CIDR spec'd IP address blocks into a database.  This involves checking for duplicates or address overlaps, both within the list with the existing database table.  If duplicates or overlaps are found, an error report is written to a python-created temporary file and vim is called to show the list of addresses and the error file side by side in a vim split window.  I want the split to be off center so that the pane with the list of addresses is narrower than the pane with the longer error statements.

If the name of the error file were fixed I could set things the way I wanted to, outside of the program, save a vim session, and then load it from the command line within the program.  What I want to do is to **start vim with the proper asymmetric vertical split** and load the address block list into the narrower window and the error file, with a dynamically created name, in the 2nd, wider window.  I can create a split using something like `:30vs`. or resize and existing split with ":vertical res 30" in a .vimrc file but the asymmetry is overridden if I use the -O option to load two files.  Is there any way to do this in vim using a dynamically generated temporary file as one of the editing targets?

Comment: Wow, that is one long problem description. You might want to get to the point a bit quicker :)

Comment: Peter, this is a relatively _brief_ summary of what has been a lengthy thought and experimentation process.  Sorry, but my experience has been that unless I go into detail on a question I get a lot of off-point answers.

Comment: Peter, as per your suggestion, I edited my question as best I could to shorten it a bit without losing essential content.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-o` / `-O` / `-p` command-line arguments only cover the frequent cases of (equal-sized) splits / tab pages, but you can create any arbitrary window layout via the same commands you'd use inside Vim, passed via `-c {cmd}`. For example:

```
$ vim -c "edit errorfile.txt" -c "leftabove 30vsplit addressblock.txt"
```

You can also combine this will explicitly passed `{filename}` arguments (which are opened first). For very complex setups (the number of `-c` arguments is limited to 10, and command chaining (`edit foo | split bar`) becomes incomprehensive soon, too), you can extract all commands into an external Vimscript, and launch that via `-S {scriptname}`.

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I need.  Because the temporary filename changes with each run of the program, its name must be an argument which can be dynamically provided to a `subprocess.open()` python call.